# Factory Pattern with Generic Type Constraints

Tags: c#, generics, factory-pattern

I am implementing a type of factory pattern and found [this neat-looking pattern](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/8307/implementing-factory-design-pattern-with-generics/8586#8586?newreg=6f780f55dd4a46e5a7bfd792420cfc0e) on Code Review.

I've implemented this solution with some variations as follows:

I have a factory class which looks like this:

```
public class SearchableServiceFactory<TSearchableLookupService, TOutputDto>
    where TOutputDto : IBaseOutputDto
    where TSearchableLookupService : ISearchableLookupService<TOutputDto>
{
    static readonly Dictionary<string, Func<TSearchableLookupService>> _SearchableLookupServicesRegistry =
        new Dictionary<string, Func<TSearchableLookupService>>();

    private SearchableServiceFactory() { }

    public static TSearchableLookupService Create(string key)
    {
        if (_SearchableLookupServicesRegistry.TryGetValue(
            key, out Func<TSearchableLookupService> searchableServiceConstructor)
        )
            return searchableServiceConstructor();

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public static void Register<TDerivedSearchableService>
    (
        string key,
        Func<TSearchableLookupService> searchableServiceConstructor
    )
        where TDerivedSearchableService : TSearchableLookupService
    {
        var serviceType = typeof(TDerivedSearchableService);

        if (serviceType.IsInterface || serviceType.IsAbstract)
            throw new NotImplementedException();

        _SearchableLookupServicesRegistry.Add(key, searchableServiceConstructor);
    }
```

That works. I call it from code, thus:

```
...
SearchableServiceFactory<OrgLookupService, OrgOutputDto>.Register<OrgLookupService>
(
    nameof(Organization), () => new OrgLookupService(_Context, _OrganizationRepository)
);
...
```

That works. A constructor is added to the dictionary, along with a key. Then I go to retrieve that constructor by key, to get an instance and do something with it, like so:

```
SearchableServiceFactory<ISearchableLookupService<IBaseOutputDto>, IBaseOutputDto>.Create(myKey).DoAThing();
```

That fails because no such value exists in the dictionary. Because it's static, as are the methods in the class that register and create the instances I need.

I'm using .NET Core 2.1, if that matters (this seems like a strictly C# issue).

Comment: `SearchableServiceFactory<OrgLookupService, OrgOutputDto>` is not the same type as `SearchableServiceFactory<ISearchableLookupService<IBaseOutputDto>, IBaseOutputDto>`, and even the static properties are different.

Comment: That's not where the problem lies. OrglookupService implements ISearchableLookupService and OrgOutputDto implements IBaseOutputDto. That's the whole point of the example pattern to which I posted a link. My code, while inclusive of an extra type constraint argument, appears to be exactly as shown in the example, so far as I can tell.

Comment: They are still different types in the eyes of the compiler. Just because `OrglookupService` is a `ISearchableLookupService`, not every `ISearchableLookupService` is a `OrglookupService`.

Comment: The code compiles and runs fine. The issue is that I don't understand how to hang onto the instance of the dictionary object when it is static. Again, take a look at the somewhat simpler example in the example I linked to. I've implemented that code, too, exactly as shown in the accepted answer, and it doesn't work either.

Comment: But the example you link to uses the same base factory: `Factory<IAnimal>.Register<Dog>(1); Factory<IAnimal>.Register<Cat>(2);`. Hence my answer that you need to do the same if you want to use this pattern.

Answer (score 1):

`SearchableServiceFactory<OrgLookupService, OrgOutputDto>` is not the same type as `SearchableServiceFactory<ISearchableLookupService<IBaseOutputDto>, IBaseOutputDto>`, and as such, even the static properties are different.

They are different types in the eyes of the compiler. Just because `OrglookupService` is a `ISearchableLookupService`, not every `ISearchableLookupService` is a `OrglookupService`.

A possible workaround would be to use `SearchableServiceFactory<ISearchableLookupService<IBaseOutputDto>, IBaseOutputDto>` to register your object, but that would require the `ISearchableLookupService` to be covariant.

```
public interface ISearchableLookupService<out TOutputDto> 
    where TOutputDto : IBaseOutputDto
{

}
```

And register like this:

```
SearchableServiceFactory<ISearchableLookupService<IBaseOutputDto>, IBaseOutputDto>.Register<OrgLookupService>
(
    nameof(Organization), () => new OrgLookupService()
);
```

Comment: That looks promising, actually... I'm leaning at this point toward a simpler implementation of what I need to do, but I'm going to play around with this idea for a bit and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The class `SearchableServiceFactory<A, B>` is not the same class as
 `SearchableServiceFactory<X, Y>`. Therefore, you are dealing with two distinct sets of static members. Particularly, you have two different dictionaries `_SearchableLookupServicesRegistry`.

You are registering into one of them (in `SearchableServiceFactory<OrgLookupService, OrgOutputDto>`). The other one (in
`SearchableServiceFactory<ISearchableLookupService<IBaseOutputDto>, IBaseOutputDto>`) remains empty, but you are trying to use it for the retrieval of the constructor. If you set a breakpoint on the `throw` statement in `Create` and inspect `_SearchableLookupServicesRegistry`, you will see that its `Count` is `0`.

The problem with generics is that they may appear to offer some dynamic behavior, but they do not. All generic type parameters are determined a compile time. Complex scenarios using generics often tend to become highly convoluted. If you need to be highly dynamic, you must sometimes give up full type safety.

This is my suggestion for a service factory:

```
public static class SearchableServiceFactory
{
    static readonly Dictionary<string, Func<ISearchableLookupService<IBaseOutputDto>>> 
        _SearchableLookupServicesRegistry =
            new Dictionary<string, Func<ISearchableLookupService<IBaseOutputDto>>>();

    public static TSearchableLookupService Create<TSearchableLookupService>(string key)
        where TSearchableLookupService : ISearchableLookupService<IBaseOutputDto>
    {
        if (_SearchableLookupServicesRegistry.TryGetValue(
            key,
            out Func<ISearchableLookupService<IBaseOutputDto>> searchableServiceConstructor))
        {
            return (TSearchableLookupService)searchableServiceConstructor();
        }

        throw new ArgumentException($"Service for \"{key}\" not registered.");
    }

    public static void Register(
        string key,
        Func<ISearchableLookupService<IBaseOutputDto>> searchableServiceConstructor)
    {
        _SearchableLookupServicesRegistry.Add(key, searchableServiceConstructor);
    }
}
```

Note that `SearchableServiceFactory` is not generic. This is necessary to have only one single factory and consequently only one static dictionary.

It uses this modified interface having an `out` modifier. The `out` modifier adds covariance. I.e., you can supply a derived type for it; however, the generic type decorated with it must only occur as return type or in `out` parameters.

```
public interface ISearchableLookupService<out TOutputDto> where TOutputDto : IBaseOutputDto
{
    TOutputDto GetOutputDto();
}
```

You can register with

```
SearchableServiceFactory.Register(
    nameof(Organization), () => new OrgLookupService(_Context, _OrganizationRepository));
```

and create with

```
IBaseOutputDto result = SearchableServiceFactory
            .Create<ISearchableLookupService<IBaseOutputDto>>(nameof(Organization))
            .GetOutputDto();
```

or to get a more concrete type

```
OrgOutputDto result = SearchableServiceFactory
    .Create<ISearchableLookupService<OrgOutputDto>>(nameof(Organization))
    .GetOutputDto();
```

But this last example makes the string key `nameof(Organization)` redundant, as the type of `OrgOutputDto` itself could be used as key. (I would require some Reflection to extract it from `TSearchableLookupService`.)

Comment: Okay, yeah... now I think I get what you're saying. So it's clear, can you post an example of the code, fixed?

Comment: The fix would consist in making the methods generic instead of the class. But most probably you would run into other problems, because `S<T>` and `S<TDerived>` are not assignment compatible. They are two distinct types.

Comment: Yeah, I I did try that too, and yes, ran into other issues. There are other patterns I can use to solve the issue I need solved, but this one looked promising. Did you take a look at the code example I linked to--i.e., the accepted solution? It looks like (somehow?) it is supposed to work, but I don't get it.

Comment: The overall pattern in your suggestion here is correct so far as I can tell and should work, but now I am stuck on one last thing, which is: what if the "DoAThing()" that I need to do is return an object or list of objects of type TOutputDto?

Comment: Google for "Repository pattern" for ideas. It's really up to you.

Comment: Sure, but what I'm not getting is if I define ISearcableLookupService with ISearchableLookupService<out T>, and then in that interface I need to define a method that returns T, when T is an interface, how do I do that?

Comment: I replaced `DoAThing` with a more meaningful example (`GetOutputDto`).